# SOAP: Fatal Error .. Could not connect to host

Tags: php, soap

I've tried everything I can think of to no avail, and hope you can help.

I've taken on a site from another web dev, so am working on existing code.

The code works on my own development server (debian VM on my Win7 machine), but not on the live server (WHM/cPanel admin'd REDHAT Enterprise 5.4 x86_64 standard).

I get the following error after the call to `$BHclient->startSession`:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host in /home/aap3r/public_html/soap_test.php:60
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'https://api.bul...', '', 1, 0)
#1 /home/aap3r/public_html/soap_test.php(60): SoapClient->__call('startSession', Array)
#2 /home/aap3r/public_html/soap_test.php(60): SoapClient->startSession(Object(stdClass))
#3 {main}
  thrown in /home/aap3r/public_html/soap_test.php on line 60
```

The WDSL file is downloaded okay (though it appears to have the wrong mime-type).

Since the exact same test code works on one server but not another I thought it was a firewall issue, but the host denies it.

The relevant code:

```
$url = "http://api.bullhornstaffing.com/webservices-2.0/?wsdl";

ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled',1);
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl',1);

$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$apiKey = "xxxx";

$session_request = new stdClass();
$session_request->username = $username;
$session_request->password = $password;
$session_request->apiKey = $apiKey;

$BHclient = new SoapClient($url, array("trace" => true, "exception" => false));

$API_session = $BHclient->startSession($session_request);

print_r($API_session);
```

`phpinfo` confirms that SOAP is installed, and I've tried the various implementation/installation methods presented in the control panels.

I've updated to PHP Version 5.3.27 and Apache to 2.2.25.

Any help will be hugely appreciated.

---

Update: I've found a workaround. For whatever reason the production server couldn't connect to HTTP*S*, so I copied and rehosted the WDSL file after manually editing it to replace the protocol.

Comment: Have you shell access to the server?

Comment: if you try `wget 'https://api.bullhornstaffing.com/webservices-2.0/?wsdl'`, does it work? (note the `https`)

Comment: @hek2mgl Why do you ask? Does SOAP use SSL connections?

Comment: not in general, but in your wsdl the service port is hard-coded `https`

Comment: try to craft simple php cli script with the code above and execute it like this `strace php your.php 2>&1`.. Would like to see the output (on pastebin, of course). Before posting it: Make sure passwords and credentials aren't visible

Comment: @hek2mgl Thanks for your help so far. I don't understand what's in this output, and it was too big for any online pastebins that I know of, so I've uploaded it at http://dev.jezmckean.com/soap_strace.txt

Comment: it is a trace of syscalls I hope to get some info about network activity out of that. Btw, is it a root server or shared server

Comment: While I see that there is some network traffic, for me it looks like it is using the wrong IP for `bullhornstaffing.com`. Hard to say more from here

Comment: Okay, thanks. Where in that output can you tell that it's using the wrong IP? It'd be useful to be able to show the host that there's a problem. I guess it could be bad NS cache or something?

Comment: I have tried `grep socket -A 10 -B 10 soap_strace.txt` You see that there is some successful networking. Be later on a poll is made on the socket unsuccessfully. It's to early to say it is an DNS problem and maybe a wrong assumption (I think now). Would really like to see the output of `tcpdump`. Can you get root on that machine?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't answer before - yes I have root access.  A very short snippet of plain tcpdump: http://dev.jezmckean.com/tcpdump.txt

Comment: BTW, the host have said that 89.151.64.70 is a DNS.

Comment: Nice, you can execute tcpdump! :) Can you do the following(?): First execute `tcpdump -s65535 -ieth0 -w"soap.pcap"`, then run your script in another shell, then stop tcpdump, then analyze "soap.pcap" in `wireshark`. If the network interface that is being used for the route is not `eth0`, then replace `eth0` by the proper network interface

Comment: I don't have a GUI, but read that I can use tshark, here's the output (assuming I understood correctly!) http://dev.jezmckean.com/tshark.txt Again, I'm sorry that I don't really understand what this is showing me. I also saved http://dev.jezmckean.com/soap.pcap in case it's useful.

Comment: thanks for the files! especially the last one is helpful. I can now say that it is not a DNS problem. something strange happened: after some successful communication, *your* server closes the connection, not the remote end. It's hard to say *why* this happens as the communication is encrypted.. One thing that comes in mind is that the credentials could be wrong. Are you sure that your credentials for bullhornstuffing are ok?

Comment: I believe the credentials must be correct because the same code works on another server. I will have to ask the host again, vielen dank!

Comment: :) really hard to say (as the communication is crypted). I currently see 2 things we can do now: Contact the support of bullhornstuffing, or decrypt the ssl traffic for debugging. (Latter would require me having acccess to the machine or at least to your private key, you would have to regenerate them after this)

Comment: I've found a work around - I've copied and hosted my own copy of the WDSL after replacing https with http. I wish I'd tried this sooner (the 6th comment suggest it indirectly)!

Comment: Yep, that's a smart workaround (for debugging). Can I ask whether using http solves the problem completely or did just lead you to the problems solution (because traffic is unencrypted) ?

Comment: It solves the problem completely, as long as the API authors don't change anything! In this case I don't think they will, since they've already moved to REST anyway.  Thanks for all your help, would you like to add an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would record the network traffic with `tcpdump`:

```
tcpdump -s65535 -iYOUR_INTERFACE -w soap.pcap
```

You can analyze the traffic (`soap.pcap`) using `wireshark`.